# HTML Agilitypack - Use webclient to download HTML from a website and store it

Tags: c#

I am trying to download the insides of a website using the HTML Agilitypack. I want to store it in a variable type HTML but it doesn't work and I don't really know how to explain it so here is my code:

```
  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = client.DownloadString(URL);
```

Sadly this throws an error("Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument")

How can I fix this and can someone explain what I am doing wrong and how I can do it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(client.DownloadString(URL));
```

You need to to use `LoadHtml` method to create the `HtmlDocument`.

Comment: @Kaneke you can mark the answer as correct if helped you.